# Cbtransfer does not work: no bucket subdirectories at: {path}

Tags: couchbase

I'm trying to transfer data from one bucket to another, with:

```
c:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin>cbtransfer couchstore-files://"C:\Program 
Files\Couchbase\Server\var\lib\couchbase\data\MyBucketToBeDeleted" 
couchbase://http://localhost:8091 --bucket-destination=MyBucket
```

But i'm getting this error:

> error: no bucket subdirectories at:
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\Couchbase\Server\var\lib\couchbase\data\MyBucketToBeDeleted

Pointless to say that `MyBucketToBeDeleted` is located at this folder (I think it is something related to syntax).

Couchbase Version: 4.5.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path should be the data directory and not the bucket directory. The URL for the cluster is also incorrect it should be `http://`

The following command should work:

```
cbtransfer couchstore-files://"C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\var\lib\couchbase\data"  http://localhost:8091 
--bucket-source=MyBucketToBeDeleted --bucket-destination=MyBucket
```